# Authentication Context token cache is undefined

Tags: cordova, sharepoint, sharepoint-online

I am trying to implement silent authentication to Sharepoint Online into my app. I have added the Office365 connected service. I am using a test page which simply populates 2 textboxes with the token and the expiry date. I have the following code (non-silent auth) that works just fine:

```
document.addEventListener('deviceready', function () {
$(document).ready(function () {
    var authContext = Microsoft.ADAL.AuthenticationContext;
    authContext.createAsync("https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/")
        .then(function (authContext) {
            authContext.acquireTokenAsync(
                "https://my.sharepoint.com",     // Resource URI
                "4be098f8-2184-4831-9ef7-3d17dbbef6a0",      // Client ID
                "http://localhost:4400/services/office365/redirectTarget.html"    // Redirect URI
            ).then(function (authResult) {
                $('#token').value = authResult.accessToken;
                $('#expire').value = authResult.expiresOn;
            }, function (err) {
                console.log(err);
            });
        }, function (err) {
            console.log(err);
        });
});
});
```

I am then trying to implement the silent auth using the code below:

```
document.addEventListener('deviceready', function () {
$(document).ready(function () {
    var authContext = Microsoft.ADAL.AuthenticationContext;
    authContext.tokenCache.readItems().then(function (items) {
        if (items.length > 0) {
            authority = items[0].authority;
            authContext = new Microsoft.ADAL.AuthenticationContext(authority);
        }
        authContext.acquireTokenSilentAsync("https://my.sharepoint.com", "4be098f8-2184-4831-9ef7-3d17dbbef6a0").then
        (function (authResult) {
            $('#token').value = authResult.accessToken;
            $('#expire').value = authResult.expiresOn;
        },
        function (authContext) {
            authContext.acquireTokenAsync(
                "https://my.sharepoint.com",     // Resource URI
                "4be098f8-2184-4831-9ef7-3d17dbbef6a0",      // Client ID
                "http://localhost:4400/services/office365/redirectTarget.html"    // Redirect URI
            ).then(function (authResult) {
                $('#token').value = authResult.accessToken;
                $('#expire').value = authResult.expiresOn;
            }, function (err) {
                console.log(err);
            });
        }, function (err) {
            console.log(err);
        }
        )
    });
});
});
```

I am getting errors when trying to read the token cache, i'm getting the tokencache as being undefined. Every sample I have seen refers to the token cache so just wonderign why it would be undefined?

Answer (score 0):

I needed to createAsync my authContext object before I could access the tokenCache...whoops